# Angular 4 - Animation not resetting to original position

Tags: javascript, angular

Have an Angular project with an animated slider that slides to the left as the time decreases. But when an action occurs that should reset the timer back to the original position, it doesn't work. The timer simply starts counting down again from the position it reached in the previous run.

My animation code:

```
animations: [
trigger('slide', [
  // start sliding state 
  state('sliding', style({
      transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
  })),
  // reset sliding div to original position
  state('notSliding', style({
      transform: 'translateX(0%)'
  })),
  transition('* => sliding', animate('60000ms linear')),
  transition('* => notSliding', animate('0ms linear'))
 ])
]
```

The samples I've looked at online all state this should work. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you setup a demo?